# 2D Plot of a stochastic spiral trajectory

Tags: plotting

In the following `X1` and `X2` represent the Cartesian coordinates [random function of, say, time]. I can plot both as a function of time as shown, using `ListLinePlot`. I want to plot the trajectory, i.e. the position of the point `[X1(t),X2(t)]` in the plane, as a function of time [the results should be a stochastic spiral, I guess]

```
X1 = TransformedProcess[t*Cos[t + x[t]], {x \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}, t];

X2 = TransformedProcess[t*Sin[t + y[t]], {y \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}, t];

X1D = RandomFunction[X1, {0, 10, 0.01}, 3];
X2D = RandomFunction[X1, {0, 10, 0.01}, 3];

ListLinePlot[X1D, PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[X2D, PlotRange -> All]

ListLinePlot[{X1D, X2D}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: BTW, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: sorry mate: what do you mean by checkmark sign?

Comment: It's under the gray up/down arrows next to an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simulate the two processes together, then extract the values of the resulting [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) with the property `"ValueList"`:

```
X12 = TransformedProcess[{t*Cos[t + x[t]], t*Sin[t + y[t]]},
  {x \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], y \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}, t];
X12D = RandomFunction[X12, {0, 10, 0.01}, 3];

ListLinePlot[X12D["ValueList"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Edit:*

In response to OP's comment below, here's a version where the two variables experience the same noise:

```
X12 = TransformedProcess[{t*Cos[t + x[t]], t*Sin[t + x[t]]}, 
   x \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], t];
X12D = RandomFunction[X12, {0, 10, 0.01}, 3];

ListLinePlot[X12D["ValueList"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks cool!

Comment: Great! Thanks. I realized that it was not quite what I wanted to do. So if you are interested by what a stochastic spiral looks like take x[t]=y[t] (THE SAME WIENER PROCESS]. That is what I had in mind. Just plotted it (as you suggested): looks great- you can have a look if interested. Thanks!